# Tracking to Google Analytics from python

Tags: python, google-analytics

I'm trying to track GA events from python backend for ecommerce analysis. The way it's written [in the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#required), that is sending a post request, nothing shows up, I still have zero visitors in the dashboard, but google replies with 200 and a GIF.

In this example I'm sending a pageview, which obviously makes no sense doing from the backend, but it's simple enough for debugging.

This is my code:

```
import requests

payload = {
    'v': 1,
    'tid': 'UA-XXXXXX-Y',
    'cid': 555,
    't': 'pageview',
    'dp': '/home',
}
print 'sending to GA...'
r = requests.post("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", data=payload)
if r.ok:
    print 'ok'
else:
    print ':('
```

I have disabled all filters in GA.

Comment: put your string together. then dump it in a web browser it can be tested using a HTTP get its easer.   Data should show up in the real-time reports. remember it takes 24 hours for data to show up in standard reports. also if this is a new Google analytics account it can take up to 48 hours for data to start showing up anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem, requests from python did not appear, postman worked. Solved it by removing the checkmark in google analytics under Settings > View > View Settings > Bot Filtering: Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an authentication problem try using postman and try your post url works or not