# Update value in of custom metric in google analytics using python

Tags: python, google-analytics

I have created a custom metric in google analytics, and I would like to update the value using python.  I have found plenty on updating the metric metadata, but not on updating the actual value.  Is this possible ?

Our situation - We have custom data stored in local mysql that we want represented in our google analytics dashboard, but we are not willing to open up inbound acl's to allow the dashboard access to our db's.  So we though we can post the data to custom metrics in GA.  If this isn't possible, or someone has opinions on other ways to handle this, we are all ears.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your scenario duplicate this one john http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987973/tracking-to-google-analytics-from-python

Comment: No it does not appear to be a duplicate.  I have created a custom metrics called ga:metric1 that does not appear to have a value in it.  I want to populate a value to report on.  Our limitation is on not allowing inbound requests from the internet to internal mysql.  If there was a way to run the google analytics dashboard locally and make api requests for report data that would be a thing - but i'm not seeing a way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Once data has been inserted into Google Analytics it can not be changed.  So if you mean that you want to change a value for a custom metric which has already been inserted for a day in into Google Analytics the answer is that you cant.

If you want to programmatically change the value of custom metric (in the admin section) which will effect all new data being inserted then you can use the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customMetrics) please note that the management api write operations are in beta you will need to apply for beta access before you can do this.

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete,
>   patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources are
>   currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're
>   interested in using these features,  [request access to the beta](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/account-management)

In my experience it can take at least a month to get access google will send you an email if you have been accepted.

Comment: No, I don't want to change data - i want to post the value of a custom metric.  I currently have ga:metric1.  it currently has no value.  I want it to have a value of 1 lets say.  I'm not finding a method for posting that value.